# covert columns to string postgresql

Tags: postgresql, type-conversion

I want to join 2 tables using one variable, but there is a problem with data type.
I was thinking of changing both date types to string and try, but it did not work as well.

This is what I have tried:

```
select count(x) , date, z from table1 p
join table2 q on p.x=q.x
group by date,z
order by date
```

How can I change the data type of x to string in both tables? original data type is given as 'character varying'

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Just try `on p.x::text=q.x::text`

Answer (score 0):

We you could try casting `x` in both tables to text:

```
select count(x) , date, z
from table1 p
inner join table2 q on p.x::text = q.x::text
group by date, z
order by date
```

This would only make sense if one of the `x` columns be already text, but the other is not.